# How to check that list is empty?

Tags: android

**I have created a list like this:**

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
List<Address>   list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
Address add = list.get(0);

if (add== null)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"address not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

The function `getFromLocationName` returns the list of addresses.
This `(Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0)`
 is thrown if none of address is found .

**I made that check for it but it's not working and my app just stops...**

Any idea why?

Comment: what about list.isEmpty()?

Comment: list.isEmpty(); check it

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Address>  list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
if(list==null || list.isEmpty())
   return; //list is empty
Address add = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list.isEmpty())
         {

             Log.i("List is Empty", "Empty List");

         }
```

//if list is not null or use list != null && list.isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

```
list != null && list.isEmpty()
```

In your case, if you want to perform something only if the list contains data, then use **`!list.isEmpty()`**

```
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address>  list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        if(list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
             Address add = list.get(0);
             if (add== null)
                {
                 Toast.makeText(this,"address not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 return;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this check

```
if(list.length() != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        Address add = list.get(0);
        if (add == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "address not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
    }
```